# The overwriting problem: first map gets overwritten with second, when stored in ArrayList, therefore can see second map twice

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, apache-poi

I am trying to store the map into ArrayList. The problem is second map is overwriting the first map. Therefore I am seeing second map twice when array list is printed

I have written code

```
public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllData(){
        loadExcelFile();
        XSSFRow rowHeader=sheet.getRow(0);
        al=new ArrayList<Movie>();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> al2=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map=new HashMap<String, String>();
        int rowCount=sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        for (int x=1; x<rowCount; x++) {
            XSSFRow row=sheet.getRow(x);
            for (int y=0; y<row.getLastCellNum(); y++) {
                String key=rowHeader.getCell(y).getStringCellValue();
                String value=row.getCell(y).getStringCellValue();
                map.put(key, value);
            }
            al2.add(map);
        }
        System.out.println(al2);
        return al2;
    }
```

There are two maps to be stored in ArrayList but I see the second map repeated twice.
Please help

Comment: So use a different map instead of using the same map repeatedly.

Comment: Move `HashMap<String, String> map = ...` inside the `for` loop, that way a new/unique one will be generated each loop cycle.

Comment: @sorifiend Thanks it worked. I placed the code outside the inner for loop it worked